# Whats wrong with my select statment?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connecton1"].ConnectionString);
conn.Open();
SqlCommand check = new SqlCommand("SELECT Location FROM Items WHERE Serial="+Convert.ToInt32(Serialtxt.Text).ToString()+"", conn);
string checker = check.ExecuteReader();
```

I'm trying to look for a piece of data in my database and assign it to a variable. The error I get is

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader' to string

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use [`ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

```
string checker = (string)check.ExecuteScalar();
```

You should also use sql-parameters to prevent sql-injection.

```
SqlCommand check = new SqlCommand("SELECT Location FROM Items WHERE Serial = @Serial", conn);
check.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Serial", Convert.ToInt32(Serialtxt.Text));
```

If you instead expect multiple rows per serial you can use `ExecuteReader` and fill a `List<string>`:

```
List<string> allLocations = new List<string>();
using(SqlDataReader rd = check.ExecuteReader())
while(rd.Read())
    allLocations.Add(rd.GetString(0));
```

Comment: ExecuteScalar will return only the first result.

Comment: @JustAndrei: but OP wants a single string. I assume that `Serial` is supposed to be unique. **Edit** However, added the reader-approach.

Comment: Most probably you're right, however I prefer stating that explicitly, because there still is a tiny chance there are many Items having the same Serial. The column name is not that obvious, ItemID would make me sure.

Comment: Yes its a Unique serial that is going to be used for Storage management.

Answer (score 1):

change the checker type from `string` to `SqlDataReader`

then you could do

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connecton1"].ConnectionString);
conn.Open();
SqlCommand check = new SqlCommand("SELECT Location FROM Items WHERE Serial           ="+Convert.ToInt32(Serialtxt.Text).ToString()+"", conn);
SqlDataReader checker = check.ExecuteReader();

    while (checker.Read())
    {
           if (checker[0] != null)
           {
              //some logic with the result
           }
    }
```